# React Virtualized List with AutoSizer - vertical scrollbar does not appear

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to use React Virtualized List together with AutoSizer.
This is my problem: I set the height of the list to be 200px, and then I see in the Chrome inspector that the height is 200, which is OK, but the overflowed content are visible even though I see that the css style of ReatVirtualized_Grid_innerScrollContainer are sat to overflow: hidden. The problem causes no vertical scroll bar and are displaying a big part of the data, but not all. So it displays a lot more data than the specified height I've sat. Why is that?

This is my code:

```
import Row from './Row';
...
render () {
  return (
    <AutoSizer disableHeight>
     {({ width })} => (
       <List
          height={200}
          width={width}
          rowCount={this.props.list.size}
          rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer}
          rowHeight={24}
        />
      )}
    </AutoSizer>
  );
}
rowRenderer = ({ key, style, index, parent }) => {
  const row = this.props.list.get(index);
  return (
    <Row
      row={row}
      style={style}
      rowIndex={index}
      parent={parent}
      columnIndex={0}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that somewhere in the project the two overflows where overriddden:

- ReactVirtualized__Grid__innerScrollContainer
- and the ReactVirtualized__Grid__innerScrollContainer inside it

So the solution was to scope this CSS that override the overflow to target only where it was needed, and not add it globally so it would affect all the React Virtualized List components.

Answer (score 0):

I had to unset the CSS property `will-change` to get the scrollbar to show using react-virtualized

```
.ReactVirtualized__Grid.ReactVirtualized__List {
  will-change: unset !important;
}
```